# Dynamically sizing Views as a percentage (or similar)?

Tags: android, user-interface

To use as an example: lets say that I have 2 [EditText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html)s and one Button that I'm using as a login form. I want the EditTexts to be the same size, one after the other, with the login [Button](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) half their widths. Something like this:

[image: example login screenshot]

The only way that I've been able to find to make the button 1/2 the width (but still maintain it's dynamic sizing) is to use a [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) with an empty view as the first field. Something like this:

```
    <TableLayout
        android:stretchColumns="0,1"
        android:shrinkColumns="0,1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/login_EditText_password">
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <Button 
                android:text="@string/login_login" 
                android:id="@+id/login_Button_login" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

That feels like a god-awful hack and there has GOT to be a better way. Do you know of one?

Comment: Actually, that's an amusing solution, and I'm not sure there's a significantly better alternative. You could use a plain `View` instead of the `TextView` for a teensy bit better performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually `layout_weight` is used to achieve [percentage like behavior](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_frm/thread/1192f89f69aba5db/e3ca2b568cf3109c). But this is usually within a parent view. You could make an empty view to take up the other half in this situation, but it's a strange use case to want the button to be half the width of the above fields.

**Edit**, here's an example:

```
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/login_EditText_password"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <View
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button 
            android:text="@string/login_login" 
            android:id="@+id/login_Button_login" 
            android:layout_width="0dip" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `android:layout_weight` will only work within one row or column.

Comment: A horizontal `LinearLayout` with an empty view of weight 1 and the button of weight 1 is essentially what this solution is doing but a little lighter and prettier.

Comment: Yeah... that is a bit cleaner. I'm going to edit your answer to provide code. I can't believe I missed that.